# Rails: inject session and current_user in class helper prior to initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do my first steps on RoR, more used to Symfony. I would like how a specific pattern could be reproduced in RoR, something like the dependency injection.

In my controllers, I will need to fetch records from the database, according to filters (passed in the query params) and the current_user (as owner of the records). Very common use case!

I've wrote an helper module, in which I've then declared a class. I'm able to instantiate this class from the controllers but I've to pass current_user and the params from the controller. I'm asking if this could be done automatically like we can do with the dependency injection on Symfony?

There is some code to explain:

```rb
# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @list_helper = ListHelper.new(Product, params, current_user)

    render :json => {
      "items": @list_helper.items,
      "page_count": @list_helper.page_count,
      "current_page": @list_helper.current_page,
    }
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if !!session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/helpers/list_helper.rb
module ListHelper
  class ListHelper
    attr_reader :page_count, :current_page

    def initialize(active_record, params, current_user) # <-- there is a way to inject 2nd and 3rd?
      @active_record = active_record
      @current_user = current_user
      @params = params

      # ...doing some stuff
    end

    def items
      # ...query
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# and obviously in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  include ListHelper
end
```

Tried the "services" pattern, but this is difficult to pass the active_record object (used for query in the helper class). A simple and good way could be to set the params before object initialization (maybe something static?), by a global? , or by injecting the application helper in the class

Thank you in advance,
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `@current_user` with `Current.user` based on [`ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html).

Create a file `app/models/current.rb` like this:

```
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
end
```

And replace your `current_user` setter method with:

```
def set_current_user
  Current.user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if !!session[:user_id]
end
```

and use the globally available `Current.user` method instead of `current_user` and without the need to pass then `current_user` into other models.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much @spickermann for your answer. In my code `current_user` was used as a getter, instead of `@current_user`. So based on your snippet, how `set_current_user` is supposed to be called? With `before_filter` or something like this?

Comment: How is `current_user` set in your application? Do you use a gem like Devise for authentication?

Comment: No, `current_user` is defined in the application_helper (there is the code in the original question post). In the actions, when I call `current_user`, the `@current_user` variable is returned unless not set (find from db in this case, singleton). But I've tried you code, and with the use of `before_action :set_current_user` in the `application_controller.rb` the job is done! Thank you!